# Correct way to get a players position

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2022

I have a UserActivities table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserActivities](
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Points] [int] NOT NULL,
```

which could have 100k+ users, each user having 1k+ activities.
I would like to be able to give query a user ID and it tells me the position.

Right now, do i have to get list all users using the below query, then filter out for my specific user? or is there a better way to get position for a specific user

```
SELECT
    UserId,
    SUM(Points) AS TotalPoints,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Points) DESC) AS UserRank
FROM
    UserActivities
GROUP BY
    UserId
ORDER BY
    TotalPoints DESC;
```

Comment: What indexes do you currently have defined on your `UserActivities` table? What does the execution plan say about your current query?

Comment: I can put any index needed on there, there isnt any right now other than the PK cluster one.  As for the plan, I was more asking if i have to retrieve all users and their points then look for the one I want or if there is a way to just get a single player and their position instead of get all users, then re-query for specific

Answer (score 2):

Working this out on the fly for an individual user is quite expensive.

If you have 100,000 users - each with 1,000 rows - then you are grouping 100 million rows each time to find a single user's rank.

Potentially you could use an indexed view to help with this

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.UserAggregatedPoints
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT UserId,
       SUM(Points) AS TotalPoints,
       COUNT_BIG(*) AS Count
FROM [dbo].[UserActivities]
GROUP BY UserId

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CUIX_UserId ON UserAggregatedPoints(UserId);

CREATE INDEX IX_Points ON UserAggregatedPoints(TotalPoints) INCLUDE (UserId);
```

This at least saves having to aggregate up the 1k+ activities for each user every time. And by pre-calculating the aggregates it can be indexed allowing the rank to be calculated by reading in index order.

Your query could then be

```
WITH Ranked AS
(
SELECT
    UserId,
    TotalPoints,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC) AS UserRank
FROM
    dbo.UserAggregatedPoints WITH (NOEXPAND)
)
SELECT TOP 1 /*No need to read any additional rows after we have got to the one for the user*/ *
FROM Ranked
WHERE UserId = @UserId 
ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC
```

For 100,000 users then on average this should end up reading ~50,000 rows for a random user (if the TotalPoints is well distributed) but with no need to do any sorting on them.

The indexed view will be maintained automatically on inserts/updates/deletes to `UserActivities` - you will have to evaluate whether the benefit to this query outweighs the cost of this for those writes.

Comment: That would get really expensive really fast, I think I might just only get top 100 users and if that user is in that list great, otherwise dont show their position at this point

Thank you for all info

Comment: @Zoinky "*That would get really expensive really fast*" - How so?...what criteria are you using to come to that conclusion?

Comment: @J.D.  I was referring to the comment about 100m groupings, and the indexed view would get slow as there would be be a lot of writes to that table.  
I might enable the exact player position when initially there isnt that many users as proposed by the indexed view,
 as more users/activities are added, i assume this query would get slower and slower even if its optimized

Comment: @Zoinky "*referring to the comment about 100m groupings*" - That's in regards to what you're currently doing with your example query. It would be slow to do that every time on the fly. The Indexed View materializes the results (like a table) so it's not doing that every time. "*as more users/activities are added, i assume this query would get slower*" - Not really. You're paying a small amount of extra time to initially write the data to the table when new data is added so that whenever you read from the Indexed View, this query is relatively faster. You'd have to test to see if it's enough.

Comment: @Zoinky - you need to test - not assume

Comment: @Zoinky It might be worth even testing a columnstore index on top of the indexed view to get batch mode processing of the `RANK()` function and columnar compression. But again, all things that would need to be tested in your current workload. No one can say what will be acceptable without actually trying it.